# detect If user exits application from homescreen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

i am new to iOS development

I want to do some task if user exits application from `homescreen`

Is there any way in which we can determine ?

**Please help, and thanks in advance !!**

Comment: And you've read about the lifecycle of an iOS app and what app delegate methods are called during each stage of the lifecycle?

Comment: yes i have read and i found when i press home button `applicationDidEnterBackground` method gets fired but in this method how to determine if user exists my app from home screen ?

Comment: OK, good.  AFAIK there is no way to determine why the app was terminated/backgrounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter didEnterBackground, you need to check the last visible controller that was on the navigation stack. If it is Home Screen, do what you want to do there.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {    
    id controller = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]])
    {
       //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: @trojanfoe When you enter didEnterBackground, you need to check the last visible controller that was on the navigation stack. If it is Home Screen, do what you want to do there.

Comment: Ah maybe I've misunderstood what the OP wanted to know.  I had assumed he wanted to know if the user pressed the home button to terminate the app, but that might not be the case.

Comment: @trojanfoe If the user presses Home button from any controller, you will get that controller in this code. Hope my answer helped you. Upvote if you feel it was correct.

Comment: It wasn't me that asked the question?!?

Comment: When i try to exit from my home screen control is not going inside if and when i try to log `NSLog(@"controller = %@",controller);` it shows me `<ViewController: 0x7fe779c9cec0>`

Comment: @KrunalLathia You need to have a navigation controller and home screen as the rootViewController for that navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {}
```

is called when your application is about to terminate.

From the Apple docs:

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any
>   final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources,
>   saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this
>   method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return.
>   If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill
>   the process altogether.

For more info take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html